# Unable to resolve target exception

Tags: java, oop

I am not sure if anyone is familiar with this exercise or programming resource. This is my working source. [addressbook-level4](https://github.com/se-edu/addressbook-level4)

I am working on developing a user authentication feature, user database being stored collectively in an XML file. Problem is it does **NOT** write/save created users into the XML although database file is created in the correct file path. More specifically, there is an error with converting data into XML and writing it into a file.

I have no clue what I am missing here, anyone kind enough to have a look, please let me know if anyone needs anything more. A big thank you for the time and patience. This would mean plenty to me.

**Stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8863)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:184)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.lambda$keyMapping$62(TextInputControlBehavior.java:330)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4083)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:4029)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2146)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected exception 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at seedu.address.storage.XmlFileStorage.saveUsersToFile(XmlFileStorage.java:46)
    at seedu.address.storage.XmlUserDatabaseStorage.saveUserDatabase(XmlUserDatabaseStorage.java:74)
    at seedu.address.storage.StorageManager.saveUserDatabase(StorageManager.java:124)
    at seedu.address.storage.StorageManager.saveUserDatabase(StorageManager.java:118)
    at seedu.address.storage.StorageManager.handleUserDatabaseChangedEvent(StorageManager.java:138)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:95)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:154)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:80)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:119)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:215)
    at seedu.address.commons.core.EventsCenter.post(EventsCenter.java:41)
    at seedu.address.commons.core.ComponentManager.raise(ComponentManager.java:26)
    at seedu.address.model.ModelManager.indicateUserDatabaseChanged(ModelManager.java:134)
    at seedu.address.model.ModelManager.addUser(ModelManager.java:159)
    at seedu.address.logic.commands.CreateUserCommand.execute(CreateUserCommand.java:43)
    at seedu.address.logic.LogicManager.executeNoLoginCommands(LogicManager.java:71)
    at seedu.address.logic.LogicManager.execute(LogicManager.java:42)
    at seedu.address.ui.CommandBox.handleCommandEntered(CommandBox.java:107)
    ... 58 more
```

**Method saveUsersToFile:**

```
public static void saveUsersToFile(Path file, XmlSerializableUserDatabase userDatabase)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            XmlUtil.saveDataToFile(file, userDatabase);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Unexpected exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

**Serializable User Database:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class XmlSerializableUserDatabase {

    @XmlElement
    private List<XmlAdaptedUser> users;

    /**
     * Creates an empty XmlSerializableUserDatabase
     * This empty constructor is required for marshalling.
     */
    public XmlSerializableUserDatabase() {
        users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Conversion
     */
    public XmlSerializableUserDatabase(ReadOnlyUserDatabase src) {
        this();
        users.addAll(src.getUsersList().stream().map(XmlAdaptedUser::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    /**
     * Converts this addressbook into the model's {@code AddressBook} object.
     *
     * @throws IllegalValueException if there were any data constraints violated or duplicates in the
     * {@code XmlAdaptedPerson} or {@code XmlAdaptedTag}.
     */
    public UserDatabase toModelType() throws IllegalValueException {
        UserDatabase userDatabase = new UserDatabase();
        for (XmlAdaptedUser user : users) {
            userDatabase.addUser(user.toModelType());
        }
        return userDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(other instanceof XmlSerializableUserDatabase)) {
            return false;
        }
        return users.equals(((XmlSerializableUserDatabase) other).users);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code in GitHub, there is a method `saveDataToFile ()` instead of `saveUsersToFile() `. Are you sure this is the correct stack trace?

Comment: Correct stack trace, I have adapted (1)`saveDataToFile()` to (2)`savaUsersToFile()`,
this is because (1) is responsible for saving other form of data into a seperate file altogether for the application. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you have a public no-arg constructor in your `XmlSerializableUserDatabase` class.

```
public XmlSerializableUserDatabase() {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works although that it leads me to a null pointer exception. (users still not created in XML file). I am grateful. I have looked into my `XMLUtil` class, on that end it works perfect (saves persons into addressbook)

Comment: You can check that the `users` list is created, before adding new user.

Comment: I have pinpoint the exact problem, it is an error with converting data into XML and writing into file. Will be updating main thread

Comment: Poked around, figured it out. Thank you.